# PHP crud update and delete function are not working

Tags: php, html, database, crud

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Resident Information</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resident_information.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php>">Barangay Awit Sayo</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="sign_in.php">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Barangay Officials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resident Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mision & Vision</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="">Documents</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Barangay Clearance</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Certificate of Residency</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Certificate of Indigency</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="">Reports and Schedules</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Blotter Records</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Settlement Schedules</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

<!-- aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -->


        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Resident Information</h1>
          <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
              <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-13">
                            <a href="#addEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Add New Resident</span></a>
                        </div>

              </div>
            </div>


          <?php
          require "config.php";
          $sql="SELECT * FROM resident";
          $sql_run= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
           ?>

            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Civil Status</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Contact No.</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

<?php
if ($sql_run) {
  foreach ($sql_run as $row) {


 ?>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_lname']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_fname']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_gender']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_age']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_cstat']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_address']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_contactno']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
<?php
  }
}else {
  echo "No Record Found";
}
 ?>
            </table>

            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="hint-text">Showing <b>5</b> out of <b>25</b> entries</div>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">1</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">2</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">3</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">4</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">5</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <!-- add Modal HTML -->
        <div id="addEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Resident</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>

            <form  action="insertcode.php" method="POST">

                        <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtfname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
                              </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                                     <label>Last Name</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="txtlname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Gender</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="txtgender" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Gender" required>
                              </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtage" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Age" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Civil Status</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtcstat" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Civil Status" required>
                  </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="txtaddress" placeholder="Enter Address" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact No.</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtcontactno" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contact No." required>
                  </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                            <input type="submit" name="insertdata" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" >
                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Edit Modal HTML -->
        <div id="editEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Resident</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>

              <form action="updatecode.php" method="POST">

              <div class="modal-body">

                <input type="hidden" name="update_id" id="update_id">

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtfname" id="txtfname" class="form-control">
                              </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                                     <label>Last Name</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="txtlname" id="txtlname" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Gender</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="txtgender" id="txtgender" class="form-control">
                              </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtage" id="txtage" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Civil Status</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtcstat" id="txtcstat" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <input type="text" name="txtaddress" id="txtaddress" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact No.</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtcontactno" id="txtcontactno" class="form-control">
                  </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                            <input type="submit" name="updatedata" class="btn btn-info editbtn" value="Save">
                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>





        <!-- Delete Modal HTML -->
        <div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Resident</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>

              <form action="deletecode.php" method="GET">

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete these Records?</p>
                            <p class="text-warning"><small>This action cannot be undone.</small></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                            <input type="submit" name="deletedata" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.editbtn').on('click', function() {

        $('#editEmployeeModal').modal('show');

          $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

          var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
              return $(this).text();
          }).get();

          console.log(data);

          $('#update_id').val(data[0]);
          $('#txtlname').val(data[1]);
          $('#txtfname').val(data[2]);
          $('#txtgender').val(data[3]);
          $('#txtage').val(data[4]);
          $('#txtcstat').val(data[5]);
          $('#txtaddress').val(data[6]);
          $('#txtcontactno').val(data[7]); 
      });
    });

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

THIS IS THE PHP EDIT/UPDATE CODE

```
    <?php
require "config.php";

    if (isset($_POST['updatedata'])) {
      $id=$_POST['update_id'];

      $fname=$_POST['txtfname'];
      $lname=$_POST['txtlname'];
      $gender=$_POST['txtgender'];
      $age=$_POST['txtage'];
      $cstat=$_POST['txtcstat'];
      $address=$_POST['txtaddress'];
      $contactno=$_POST['txtcontactno'];

      $sql="UPDATE resident SET user_fname='$fname',user_lname='$lname',user_gender='$gender',user_age='$age',user_cstat='$cstat',user_address='$address',user_contactno='$contactno' WHERE user_id='$id' ";
      $sql_run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

      if ($sql_run) {
        header("location: resident_information.php");
      }else {
        echo $conn->error;
      }
    }
?>
```

THIS IS THE PHP DELETE CODE

```
    <?php
require "config.php";

if (isset($_GET['deletedata'])) {
  $id=$_GET['deletedata'];

  $sql="DELETE FROM resident WHERE user_id=$id";
  $sql_run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

  if ($sql_run) {
    header ('location: resident_information.php');
  }
}
 ?>
```

THIS IS THE DATABASE:

[image: THIS IS THE DATABASE]

The problem of this code is that the update and delete function is not working. I did not include the create PHP code because it is working as it used to be. I only include the update and delete code because they are the one that is no working. Thanks for the help.

THIS IS THE OUTPUT:

[image: THIS IS THE OUTPUT]

Comment: What do you mean with "no working"? Do you get any error? Is PHP receiving POST data?

Comment: The add data is working just fine and it is posting. The problem is that i cant edit and delete the input